# How Can We Prove The Expected Value Is Equal To The Mean?

Tags: probability

In probability theory, the expected value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of a random variable is a measure of the central tendency of the variable's distribution. It is defined as the weighted average of all possible values that the random variable can take on, where the weights are given by the probabilities of those values.

For a discrete random variable $X$ with probability mass function $f(x)$, the expected value is defined as:
$$E[X] = \sum_x x f(x)$$

For a continuous random variable $X$ with probability density function $f(x)$, the expected value is defined as:
$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx$$

In regards to this information, I have always had these questions which I could never quite find/understand the answers to:

- 1. Can we interpret the Expected Value as the "Value with **Highest Probability**" that the "Average of the Random Variable" will assume in the long run? As of now, I am leaning towards "no" - this is because in a Continuous Random Variable, the probability of a Random Variable assuming a specific value is said to be 0. Thus, I do not think that the idea of Expected Value is associated with "Probability" per say? Wikipedia describes the Expected Value as a "measure of central tendency" - but I struggle to understand this concept of "central tendency" ... what "units" is "central tendency" measured in?
- 2. And how do we "prove" that the Expected Value is the actual "Value we Expect" a Random Variable to take in the long run? For instance, I could roll a dice many times and take the average of all numbers that appeared - thus, I could empirically conclude (via simulation) that the exact formula for the Expected Value appeared to equal the Expected Value from the simulation.... but is there a mathematical proof for this obvious concept?

Thanks!

- Note:   Just like in the case of the Statistical Mode, we can take the derivative of a Probability Distribution Function and set it to 0 - when we solve this derivative, intuitively speaking, this is the single value with the highest probability .... even though the probability of observing a single value is 0 by definition? Can a similar argument be presented for (2)?

Comment: For the 1st question, "Value with Highest Probability" and "Average of the Random Variable" are not the same, even when we consider discrete random variable

Comment: For the 2nd question is that not the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)?

Comment: Consider the toss of a fair die.  The Expected Outcome is $3.5$ which isn't even a possible outcome.  Nor are $3,4$ any more likely than any other outcomes.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind replies!